# How to derive the high dimensional image from low dimensional one without having original data (image)?

Tags: pca, image-processing, computer-vision

**Hi!
I am new to Computer Vision. I am curious as to whether it is possible to decompress a low dimensional image to a high dimensional one if I don't have an original image. What methods are applicable for this purpose? All the information, I came across on the web, is related to image compression (dimensionality reduction using PCA and reconstructing original image). I am interested in the reverse process provided I don't have the original image. I use Python. TIA**

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the subject of Image Quantisation.

You can reduce the dimensionality of your image (compress it) by Clustering -over colours, for instance.

When you do this you reduce the number of bits you need to save the whole image but you also need to save something like a dictionary that can map the reduced image into the original one.

Now, if you are given a certain compressed image, if you know how the reduction was carried, you could get something close to the original image.